# Error with JDBC using Java 9 and JMeter 4.0

Tags: sql-server, jmeter, java-9, mssql-jdbc, jmeter-4.0

I added following plugins to the JMeter :

- mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar
- mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre9.jar

When I try to execute JDBC Connection to the [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] via JMeter 4.0 with Java 9 I got issue in log :

```
    2018-04-17 17:10:54,825 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4061) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3157) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:82) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3121) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2026) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:569) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:260) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2337) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2323) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2056) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement$DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:326) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:191) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:79) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
```

Why does it happen? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: While I'd wrote this - found the answer ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
There were two plugins into the lib folder (this one and newest).
Just have deleted "jre8" and it works!

Comment: Why are you using the MySQL driver, when you are using SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a  [java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j/43601685)  issue which exclude jaxb jars (and more)

Add [jaxb-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.2.9) jar to JMeter  [lib folder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter to load jar with missing class